# Route traffic from AWS domain to Wix hosted domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, hosting, amazon-route53

I have a domain hosted on AWS (`www.example.com`) and it works fine. I have now a temporary need to route traffic from this domain to a temporary Wix hosted domain (`www.example.net`). I've tried making a CNAME to simply route from `www.example.com` to `www.example.net` but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  Does the domains not resolve to the same IP address when you do that?   Are you expecting a redirect?  If so have you implemented a redirect?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.